# Failed to create component 'ReportViewer'

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Anyone can help me with below error? It looks like it has something to do with different versions but I am not able to solve it. I followed different instructions like: Installing the NuGet package for the WinForms than adding the dll via .NET Framework components.
When I drag and drop the ReportViewer onto a Form it gives me the below error.

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did and it worked well for me:

1- Installed [Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001)

2- Opened Visual Studio and created a new project using Visual Basic > Report Application template. (You can also search for it using top right search box)

3- From the warning dialog clicked Trust

4- Cancelled Report Wizard (I just didn't want to create report initially, you can create.)

5- Rebuild the solution.

You are all set. You can add a new Report and design it in VS and show it in `ReportViewer`. If you open `Form1` you can see a `ReportViewer` there.

To add it to toolbox, you can click on Choose Items and then Browse your solution directory and from the NuGet package folders go to report viewer package folder and select `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`.

For more information on how to add report viewer control to a form see [Integrating Reporting Services Using ReportViewer Controls - Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017##adding-control-to-visual-studio-toolbar).

Comment: Where do you find Report Project template? I have Report Server Project template under Business Intelligence -> Reporting Services.

Comment: Oops, it's Report Application. Click Visual Basic node at left pane and then look at right pane. You also can search using the search box at top right.

Comment: Still the same problem. It was already what I tried to do in multiple ways. The only thing I can think of is that there are conflicting versions installed but I have no idea what to uninstall. I have like a huge list of microsoft programs installed. I even had like 6 dll files with that name, some same version, some older, some newer. Tried them all but no difference. I will try on a virtual machine environment to see if I get a different result.

Comment: I had this problem for long time in VS2017 and I followed those steps in a clean environment and I can confirm it worked well.

Comment: I used your steps in combination with this website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017##adding-control-to-visual-studio-toolbar and in a clean environment, hyper-v virtual environment and I didn't get the error so I assume something somewhere is corrupt in my main environment.

Comment: I didn't need to install package separately, because it was installed in the project template. I've read the link which you shared, it's useful.

Comment: I uninstalled everything related to visual studio and SQL server in my main environment and reinstalled the latest versions and it didn't gave the error anymore, but I have to reinstall my databases etc to give it a real test. For now it looks like it's fixed.

Comment: I have exactly the same error. I Follow these steps, and still has an error. And I do not want to reinstall everything. Any other idea? From where it referenced to these two different locations?

Comment: @parfilko All the dlls are reference from the Nuget package files (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Design, WinForms). After creating the project, using the template that is mentioned in the answer, make sure you clean and rebuild the solution and then open the form.

Comment: @selfstudy I did use new project from template exactly as said above and got error. Probably Not All the dll are reference from the Nuget package files.
As you can see on screen shot [A]-dll came from the nugget (..\ProjectAssemblies\..), and [B]-dll came from some other (SDK?, toolkit?) (..\BI\..)
I checked both dlls - they are different.
Compiler used nuggets-dll, but designer somehow used another one. I cannot find from where I should update or uninstall dll used in [B]

Comment: Problem gone after I updated SDK to latest version
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download